# Inconsistency in floating point results on Different Architecture!!! How to Proceed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intel

I am getting inconsistent floating point results when i run an application on different architecture. This happens after the third decimal point. I am able to get repeatable results on the same architecture but when i run on a different architecture i get inconsistencies in floating point results. The two architecture i'm talking about is nehalem and sandy bridge. The application is a 64 bit application. I am using Visual Studio 2010 which has Intel composer XE 2013 C++ sp1. I tried the solution recommended in the link below, but it didn't change anything. The industry in which i work, data accuracy up to 16th decimal point is extremely important. I have posted this in intel forums too. Any help is appreciated

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/consistency-of-floating-point-results-using-the-intel-compiler

Comment: How many significant digits are in front of the observed difference?

Comment: The same binary should produce the same results. But compiling two different binaries targeting the two machines might produce slightly different results depending on how the compiler chooses to optimize.

Comment: Dieter, do you mean before the decimal point? then its two.

Comment: @Mystical, the same binary is giving different results.

Comment: What are your compiler options? Floating point arithmetic is not associative. If you allow it to be associative using multiple threads or using a looser floating point model (e.g. with /fp:fast) then the same binary can give different results.

Answer (score 1):

If you need 16 digits of precision (or rely on results being *exactly* the same across all computers), then you shouldn't use floats/doubles.

Those types are great for fast, approximate results. If you really need precise results, you have to use a BigNum-like class instead.